# C++ visual studio community source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, location

I would like to know how to find the source files for visual studio projects as I need to upload my projects for marking,  I received the message is quotes below from my teacher but I am not sure where to find the .cpp and the .h / .hpp files in my visual studio project/lab folders.  I am assuming with just these files he will be able to open the projects in programs other than visual studio?

"Please just upload the source files if you can (.cpp and .h / .hpp file) – I don’t require additional Visual Studio Packages etc."

Thanks

Comment: Right-click on the tab showing your code and select 'Open containing folder'

Answer (score 0):

By default your projects are stored in "%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects" or similar depending on your version of IDE (ie. which Visual Studio version You use).

Assuming your project is named Project1, it's directory will be named the same and within this directory you will find yet another directory with the same name (so in default scenario it will all sum up to "%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1". Within this directory you shall find source (.c, .cpp) and header (.h, .hpp) files.

In most cases those files contain all the work you've done on the project. Most of other files populating project directory are non-essential, template, auto-generated or debug/release process products or by-products.

Hence to examine and judge what was written in programming language or rebuild your project in any other IDE or outside of IDE, those files would be all that's necessary.